# Flutter ToggleButtons - Failed assertion: 'children.length == isSelected.length': is not true

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement a simple row of 4 Text widgets using GridView.count() and then I am mapping it to a ToggleButtons widget.

When I run the code, I got an error message:
'package:flutter/src/material/toggle_buttons.dart': Failed assertion: line 197 pos 12: 'children.length == isSelected.length': is not true.
The error message is coming from the toggle_buttons.dart file:
[image]

Below is my code:

```
 List<bool> _selections = [false, false, false, false];

GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 4,
    children: [
      Text("one"),
      Text("two"),
      Text("three"),
      Text("four"),
    ].asMap().entries.map((widget) {
      return ToggleButtons(
          onPressed: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                buttonIndex < _selections.length;
                buttonIndex++) {
              if (buttonIndex == index) {
                _selections[buttonIndex] = true;
              } else {
                _selections[buttonIndex] = false;
              }
            }
          });
        },
        isSelected: _selections,
        children: [widget.value],
      );
    }).toList()),
```

Answer (score 1):

1. why are you using Grid? I don't get the point to use it. if you specify what you want then we can try to get a solution in your way.
2. the result in a new way.

```
ToggleButtons(
        onPressed: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                buttonIndex < _selections.length;
                buttonIndex++) {
              if (buttonIndex == index) {
                _selections[buttonIndex] = true;
              } else {
                _selections[buttonIndex] = false;
              }
            }
          });
        },
        isSelected: _selections,
        children: [
          Text("one"),
          Text("two"),
          Text("three"),
          Text("four"),
        ],
      ),
```

as you said

```
GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: List.generate(10, (index) {
          return ToggleButtons(
            onPressed: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                    buttonIndex < _selections.length;
                    buttonIndex++) {
                  if (buttonIndex == index) {
                    _selections[buttonIndex] = true;
                  } else {
                    _selections[buttonIndex] = false;
                  }
                }
              });
            },
            isSelected: _selections,
            children: [
              // add your list (static or dynamic )
              Text("one"),
              Text("two"),
              Text("three"),
              Text("four"),
            ],
          );
        }),
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The reason I want to use GridView.count() is because I want to define the four widgets first so I can adjust the layout of the widgets later on.

Comment: Based on the error, it seems like my _selections is length 4, and my children in the ToggleButton is a list of widget.value which is length of 1. And of course, 4 != 1. I'm not sure what I should do to solve this.

Comment: okay, so you have more than 4 toggles? if it is just four it will be displayed in the first row. or do you want it in full width?

Comment: Currently, I am only using 4 toggle buttons. I wish to use GridView so that I predefine the 4 widgets first so that the 4 text widgets will evenly take up the width of the screen. Later on, I'll be implementing another set of toggle buttons with two rows, so I want to learn implementing using gridview with togglebuttons.

Comment: okay, got your point now, I will be back with some solution.

Comment: let me know you get your result or not. this code generates 2 columns with 4 items, if you want only single row than remove grid layout use listview only

Comment: I ended up figuring out the issue for my posted code. I changed `isSelected: _selections,` to `isSelected: [_selections_howOften[widget.key]]` 
I used this site for resource:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64393934/4041127
I'm not fully sure the reason for it, but it works.

Comment: I also changed `if (buttonIndex == index) {` to  `if (buttonIndex == widget.key) {`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers go here and learn how KEY works.
the key is not like the index. so buttonIndex == widget.key is not true.
Key has some dip down concept so please learn the key concept from above link.